# proxy pass aws api gateway from existing nginx lb

Tags: nginx, lambda, aws-api-gateway, proxypass

I'm exploring options to invoke a lambda function via an HTTP call using AWS api gateway. I have an existing Nginx load balancer, serving micro services. When I try to add a location block adding a proxy pass to the aws api gateway,

```
location /foo {
  proxy_pass <aws api gateway url>;
}
```

this is resolving the hostname to IP eg: 10.20.30.40, but AWS API gateway is returning 400 Bad Request when querying directly from the IP.

Is there any way I can invoke lambda using AWS API gateway from my existing nginx server?

Comment: Does this work if you use the deployed URL and not the ARN?

Comment: edited the question, I'm using the URL.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, API Gateway will return an error if you try to access by IP. You must configure your proxy to send the `Host` header as if you were accessing the API directly. According to the nginx documentation this is achieved via the `proxy_pass_header` directive.

Comment: thank you, added `proxy_ssl_server_name on` for this to work. As you mentioned the server name was not being passed and on setting the header it was able to.